# Настройка дебаггера в phpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, ide

Добрый день. Не подскажете, как настроить дебаггер в phpStorm?
Зарание благодарен.

Answer (score 4):

Все очень просто)
Run->Edit Configurations. Откроется окно с конфигурациями дебага. Нажимаешь Insert -> PHP Web Application. В окне вводишь Name, напротив server нажимаешь на ... В окне вводишь name и host (test.local). Нажимаешь ОК. Выбираешь сервер. Start url ставишь "/".
Debug - Break at the first line. Browser - default. Нажимаешь ОК. Shift+F9 и будет счастье. 
Перед этим только убедись что у тебя поставлен и корректно работает xdebug. Посмотреть это можно через ф-ю php - phpinfo();
Удачи

Comment: Ответ немного устарел: "Нажимаешь Insert -> PHP Web Application" - PHP Web Application не существует